# Enumerate item refering to theorem environment

Tags: cross-referencing, enumerate

In the conclusion part of my paper, I am creating a enumerated list using the `enumerate` enviroment.

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{Property \arabic*.}, leftmargin=25mm]
\item Stationarity
\item Autocorrelation
\end{enumerate}
```

Using this enumerated list, I am creating an overview of several properties I have found and listed throughout my paper using a newly defined theorem environment:

```
\newtheorem{property}{Property})
```

which I reference throughout the text using

```
\begin{property}\label{prop:stationarity}[Stationarity] The data xyz is stationary.\end{property}
```

In the text I can easily refer to the properties using references like:

```
As we have found in property \ref{prop:stationarity}, data xyz is...
```

Now, I would like to do something similar in the enumerated list, but I would like the item itself to be the reference to the property. To explain it in simple words, I would like to click on the "Property 1." in the enumerated list and then be referenced to the actual property 1 defined in the paper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a programming point of view, there is no relationship between `Property 1` (what you see printed in the document) and `prop:stationarity` (what you supply as the label/reference). So it would be difficult to automate such a cross-reference scheme.

Instead, using a manual cross-reference scheme is possible:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,hyperref}
\newtheorem{property}{Property}
\begin{document}

\begin{property}[Stationarity]\label{prop:stationarity}
The data $xyz$ is stationary.
\end{property}

As we have found in Property~\ref{prop:stationarity}, data $xyz$ is\ldots

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=25mm]
  \item[{\hyperref[prop:stationarity]{Property~\ref*{prop:stationarity}}}] Stationarity
  \item[Property~2] Autocorrelation
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, that worked without any trouble for all properties. Thanks!